# What is the scope of the SET LANGUAGE clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005

What is the scope of the SET LANGUAGE clause in SQL Server 2005 and above?

Comment: [According to docs it is scoped to the session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx).

Comment: Just one doubt: If I use SET LANGUAGE inside a stored procedure, the setting remains out of it, affecting the next statements of the calling script?

Comment: I just tested my last comment. In that case, its effect remains just inside the stored procedure, and doesn't affect the outer following statements.

Comment: Many thanks @MikaelEriksson, could you put your comment as an answer, to select it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SET LANGUAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx) is scoped to the session.